# c# profiling aspx page loadtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, profiling

I would like to profile the loading of an aspx page to determine the bottlenecks, without using an outside tool.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Profiling ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066807/profiling-asp-net)

Comment: IF you want to find out the bottlenecks you have 2 choices - either use some profiler (highly recommended) or sprinkle your code with logging information including timestamps and then look at the logged information...

Comment: @anna:  That question asks for tools.  I am specifically looking for how to do it without tools.

Comment: @Yahia: I have tried "sprinkling the code", but the problem is a lot of stuff happens under the hood.  I suppose I could add a HttpModule, but I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: I don't see a reliable way to do this without tools - if you don't want to write your own profiler I would highly recommend RedGate Performance Profiler - see http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Page Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx) might give you a start but this doesn't give you memory usage etc, only timings.

Comment: interesting.  Too bad there's a sortByTime but not SortByTimeDifference.  But this will help I think.

Comment: BTW, the file Trace.axd can't be found on the system.  Just look for it using the browser.  Unfortunately it doesn't give any timing information on individual controls.  That will be my next task.

Answer (score 2):

[ANTS Memory Pro filer](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) is the best tool I have found for things like that.

Comment: Looks like a good tool, but I was looking for no tool.  I'll check it out thanks.